# Linq How to combine List Items to other List items

Tags: vb.net, list, linq

I have multiple list of string with some items

want to combine every items together like below

```
        Dim _rsltitm = Nothing
        For Each _itm1 In _lst1
            For Each _itm2 In _lst2
                For Each _itm3 In _lst3
                    _rsltitm &= vbNewLine & _itm1 + _itm2 + _itm3
                Next
            Next
        Next
```

above code is working fine but i have more than 8 lists or sometimes 11

so i need linq to combine multiple list of string items together

i am trying like this but i could not

```
    Dim _rslt = From itm In _lst1 Select (Function(x) From itm2 In _lst2 Select (Function(d) x & d))
```

Comment: You only need three loops, no matter how many lists you have. You combine the first two lists into one list, then you combine that with the next list to get one more list, then you combine that with the next list and so on. The inner two loops do the combining and the outermost loop goes over the list of all lists. As with any problem, you should start by doing it manually and working out the steps involved to develop an algorithm. Implementing that algorithm in code should be the last thing you do.

Comment: Once you have a non-LINQ implementation, you could presumably convert that to LINQ using `Aggregate`, although I haven't thought through the specifics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested this code and it seems to do what you want:

```
Dim list1 As New List(Of String) From {"1", "2", "3"}
Dim list2 As New List(Of String) From {"A", "B", "C"}
Dim list3 As New List(Of String) From {"7", "8", "9"}
Dim list4 As New List(Of String) From {"X", "Y", "Z"}

Dim lists = {list1, list2, list3, list4}

Dim result = lists.Aggregate(Function(current, list)
                                 Dim combinedList As New List(Of String)

                                 For Each prefix In current
                                     combinedList.AddRange(From suffix In list Select prefix & suffix)
                                 Next

                                 Return combinedList
                             End Function)
```

You just add all your lists to that `lists` array and `result` should end up containing the desired result.

I feel like that Lambda body should be able to be LINQified a bit more but my initial attempts didn't work so I gave up quickly. If you want to put some more time into it, you're welcome to.

EDIT:

Here's that in a function:

```
Private Function CombineLists(ParamArray lists As List(Of String)()) As List(Of String)
    Return lists.Aggregate(Function(current, list)
                               Dim combinedList As New List(Of String)

                               For Each prefix In current
                                   combinedList.AddRange(From suffix In list Select prefix & suffix)
                               Next

                               Return combinedList
                           End Function)
End Function
```

In my example, I could either call that like so:

```
Dim result = CombineLists(list1, list2, list3, list4)
```

or like so:

```
Dim lists = {list1, list2, list3, list4}

Dim result = CombineLists(lists)
```

Comment: everything working as perfect joined 11 lists and get desired result thanQ so much .. really appreciate

Comment: i will add this function to my all projects ... very useful snippet